# Angular 2 ngOnChanges not firing on rapidly changing input

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ngonchanges

I am using an Angular 2 @Input property to pass desired numeric values to the child component like this.

Parent component:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'test-parent',
 template: '<button (click)="raiseCounter()">Click me!</button><test-child [value]="counter"></test-child>'
})

export class ParentComponent {
 public counter: number = 0;

 raiseCouner() {
  this.counter += 1;
  this.counter += 1;
  this.counter += 1;
 }
}
```

Child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test-child'
});

export class ChildComponent implments OnChanges {
 @Input() value: number = 0;

 ngOnChanges() {
  if (this.value) {
   this.doSomeWork();
  }
 }

 doSomeWork() {
  console.log(this.value);
 }
}
```

In this scenario, the OnChanges lifecycle hook is triggered only once instead of 3 times, showing that the input value changed from 0 to 3. However I need it to be triggered every time the value changes (0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, etc..). Is there a way how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected behavior.
Angular2 runs change detection when the `(click)` event handler has been completed, which is after the 3rd `+= 1`.
When change detection updates an `@Input()` binding, then `ngOnChanges()` is called.